# Полный контроль над другими приложениями из формы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, unity3d, render

Здравствуйте!
Хотел узнать у опытных программистов: возможно ли выполнять отрисовку окна другого приложения и перенаправлять ввод-вывод из своего приложения в это приложение?

Т.е. я бы хотел, чтобы внутри моего приложения WPF был некоторый Image, в котором бы отрисовывалось окно сторонней программы, если содержимое этого окна изменяется, то Image перерисовывает окно. При этом, если был клик по Image в какой-либо точке, то для этого стороннего окна происходит событие клика в той точке, которую я кликнул на картинке.

Возможно ли реализовать это с помощью WinAPI и в каком направлении следует искать решение данной проблемы?

Заранее благодарен,
proggamer12

Например, как реализована данная программа: http://store.steampowered.com/app/382110/

Answer (score 2):

Ну если в лоб, то можно найти окно интересующей программы и получить окно "цель"

```
     [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow (string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Получить область этого окна

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);
```

затем запустить таймер сканирующий область этого окна и при изменениях, перерисовывать это в своем Image. 
 Что касается кликов, так как у вас есть дубликат координат этого окна, то можно транспонировать координаты для окна "цели" и через WinApi вызвать клик мыши по координатам.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
```